# Eclipse acting oddly, often unresponsive on Run

Tags: java, android, eclipse, compilation

My Eclipse installation has been giving me greif today. After corrupting my Android project to where it would not build any more  I was forced to reinstall both eclipse and re-create my project from Scratch.

However, eclipse is still acting oddly. When I press the green Run button in the tool bar quite often it appears to do nothing. No dialog, no progress indicators, no output on the console. If I leave it for a bit and/or hammer the run button constantly, eventually it runs.

What is going on. Have I ticked a 'Run in Background' check box somewhere by mistake. If and even if not, how can I re-configure eclipse to be just a little more responsive again.

**EDIT: Turns out in the project settings Eclipse had enabled XML validation for every type of check, this has sped things up a little. However, it's still far from as it was when working well. My guess is there are a number of esoteric lesser used settings enabled somehow. I would still like to know how *not* to have the Run progress in the background.**

Comment: your eclipse is most surely drunk. Please avoid feeding the computer with vodka.

Comment: you update to ADT 22 but you missed to install the newest ANDROID SDK Build-tools

Comment: did you try checking the logcat from window->view->logcat ?
this or i think there might be a ram shortage for your AVD

Comment: Maybe post your Eclipse config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem, sometimes it works and sometimes not. My solution when it happens just click right button on your project in Package Explorer -> Run As -> Android application.

Comment: This works for me.  In addition I had set the Run and Debug settings in Eclipse to run in background and just unchecked this option.

Answer (score 1):

Check if disabling Project > Build Automatically and optimizing memory settings in eclipse.ini works.

Comment: Or migrate to Android Studio released at the recent Google I/O... It received some good feedback's...